# Mypy fails to infer enums being created from a list variable

Tags: python, enums, mypy

Enums can be created by taking in a list of possible members, which I'm doing like so:

```py
# example_issue.py
import enum

yummy_foods = ["ham", "cheese"]
foods = enum.Enum("Foods", yummy_foods)
cheese = foods.cheese
```

This looks OK, and runs fine, but mypy returns

```
example_issue.py:4: error: Enum() expects a string, tuple, list or dict literal as the second argument
example_issue.py:5: error: "Type[foods]" has no attribute "cheese"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

What is mypy doing here, and why can't it follow that `foods` can take any value in `yummy_foods`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a variable `yummy_foods` is too dynamic for mypy's static type checking, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4865#issuecomment-592560696).

If you change your code to generate the `Enum` as:

```
foods = enum.Enum("Foods", ["ham", "cheese"])
```

mypy will then be able to figure out which attributes exist on the enumeration.